# Какой падеж у прилагательного "доброе начало"?

Tags: падежи

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос не очень понятен. Вы спрашиваете про падеж прилагательного "доброе"?
Он тот же, что и у существительного, но не определяется без контекста, может быть именительным или винительным, фразу целиком приведите.

Answer (score 1):

Если "кто, что?" - им.падеж, если "кого, что?" - вин. падеж. Без контекста не понять.